# ADO - future Path for Access databases

Tags: ms-access, excel, ado, vba

Will I be able to create access database back-ends (on machines without MS Access installed) using ADO and DDL in an Excel 2010 or 2013 (32-bit) on a Win-8 or 8.1 system?

There is a *lot* behind this question that I am not writing here, fueling my anxiety - having to do with JET support being dropped, uncertainty about where ACE really resides (in Windows? / in Office? / in Access (only) libraries) - etc...

I want to make sure that using 32-bit Excel and a few project references, I can create back-ends on the fly and store and retrieve data.

Thanks.

Comment: Unless Access is essential, why not use something more modern and lightweight like SQL LocalDB or SQL Lite?

Comment: @martin_costello On the other hand, if the OP wants ad-hoc database storage for 32-bit Excel applications then why install something else when Jet is already on the machine (as I explained in my answer)?

Comment: I like all the answers here, thank you. I started trying SSCE but it did not work well with my Visual Studio 2013 and I will try SQL LocalDB. I appreciate knowing Jet is not dead and also learning ACE will work without Access installed.  Lots if options, now I know not everything needs to be a nail because I won't be forced to have a hammer as the only tool.

Answer (score 1):

The older "Jet" database engine is still part of a standard Windows install, including Windows 8.1. It is only available to 32-bit applications because there is no 64-bit version of Jet, and it can only work with .mdb files (not .accdb files). Yes, Jet has been officially deprecated, but for now it is still a viable option in the 32-bit world.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Access database engine redistributable that is intended to give you a migration path off of Access: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

But, it looks like you may be able to use it as an actual database engine if you want, even though it's not recommended.

Comment: re: "migration path off of Access" - You mean "migration path from Jet", right? re: "you may be able to use it as an actual database engine if you want, even though it's not recommended" - Umm, if the ACE redistributable is offered as a current download then what makes you think that using it as "an actual database engine" is not recommended? The download page you cited does say that ACE *is* supported for "Desktop applications which read from and write to various files formats including Microsoft Office Access, Microsoft Office Excel and text files."

Comment: @GordThompson - no, I mean migration path from Access to something else. To answer your second question, I think they make it pretty clear what this redistributable is & isn't intended for. I believe the points listed in the 'Details' section support my wording.